# how to declare object with recursive properties? in nodejs

Tags: javascript, object

I am declaring:

```
var ENV       = {
    VERSION: 1,
    SERVER: 'midomain.com',
    SERVER_DEV: 'testdomain.dev',
    API_ROUTE: 'socket/',
    API: (false) ? this.SERVER + '/' + this.API_ROUTE : this.SERVER_DEV + '/' + this.API_ROUTE };
```

should get:

```
{ VERSION: 1,SERVER: 'midomain.com',SERVER_DEV: 'testdomain.dev',API_ROUTE: 'socket/', API: 'testdomain.dev/socket/' }
```

but I get

```
{ VERSION: 1,SERVER: 'midomain.com',SERVER_DEV: 'testdomain.dev',API_ROUTE: 'socket/',  API: 'undefined/undefined' }
```

Comment: use an object and a constructor, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030739/javascript-how-to-define-a-constructor. You pass the version, the server, the API route and you build the API from it. Note that with that you can extract the server_dev outside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in that case  context is global, not an your object. You can check it with an example:

```
window.b = 666;

let a = {
 prop: this.b
}

console.log(a); // display: {prop: 666}
```

You can fill your object properties one-by-one

```
let ENV       = {};
ENV.VERSION = 1;
ENV.SERVER = 'midomain.com';
ENV.API = ENV.SERVER;
```

or create function with 'new' syntax

```
var ENV = new function() {
   this.VERSION = 1;
   this.SERVER = 'midomain.com';
   this.API = this.SERVER;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I used
const ENV = new function () {
 this.VERSION    = 1;
 this.SERVER     = 'domain.com';
 this.SERVER_DEV = 'testdomain.dev';
 this.API_ROUTE  = 'socket/';
 this.API        = (process.env.PROD) ? this.SERVER + '/' + this.API_ROUTE : this.SERVER_DEV + '/' + this.API_ROUTE;
 return this;
}();